# Joins in R with multiple OR statements

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes - `test` and `idx`  - my goal is to use `merge()` or a similar function to make a conditional join.

For example, `test` has ids with multiple possible keys (and NA values in some).  You wont find the same keys for two separate `ids`, the keys will always be unique.

```
> test
   id keyA keyB keyC
1 foo   NA    2   10
2 bar    1   NA    6
3 baz    7   NA    4
4  li    8    3   NA
5 qux    9   NA   NA
```

My goal is to join with `idx` where there is any match in keys, for example:

```
> idx
  key value
1   2    NA
2  10    NA
3   7    NA
4   4    NA
5   9    NA
```

The join should output:

```
> idx
  key value
1   2   foo
2  10   foo
3   7   bar
4   4   bar
5   9   quz
```

I understand how to use `merge` on one or multiple columns, but am not sure how to use it when there is an `OR` statement involved ( in this case, the match would be on keyA OR keyB OR keyC)

How would one perform this join in R?

the data:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(id = c("foo", "bar", "baz", "li", "qux"), keyA = c(NA, 
1, 7, 8, 9), keyB = c(2, NA, NA, 3, NA), keyC = c(10, 6, 4, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dput(idx)
structure(list(key = c(2, 10, 7, 4, 9), value = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do that:

```
library(tidyverse)

nest(test, -id) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(key = list(idx$key[idx$key %in% data])) %>%
  unnest(key, .drop = T) %>%
  select(key, value = 'id')

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# key value
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     2 foo  
# 2    10 foo  
# 3     7 baz  
# 4     4 baz  
# 5     9 qux
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `gather` `test` to long form and then `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

idx %>%
  left_join(test %>%
             gather(key, value, -id, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("key" = "value")) %>%
   select(key, id)

#  key  id
#1   2 foo
#2  10 foo
#3   7 baz
#4   4 baz
#5   9 qux
```

---

Or as @David Arenburg mentions using `data.table` that would be

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(test), "id")[setDT(idx), on = .(value = key), .(key, id)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the solution you are looking for, but you can do it by melting the test data.frame using the melt function from the reshape2 package.

```
test <- structure(list(id = c("foo", "bar", "baz", "li", "qux"), keyA = c(NA, 
1, 7, 8, 9), keyB = c(2, NA, NA, 3, NA), keyC = c(10, 6, 4, NA, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

library(reshape2)
melted_test <- melt(test)

melted_test
Using id as id variables
    id variable value
1  foo     keyA    NA
2  bar     keyA     1
3  baz     keyA     7
4   li     keyA     8
5  qux     keyA     9
6  foo     keyB     2
7  bar     keyB    NA
8  baz     keyB    NA
9   li     keyB     3
10 qux     keyB    NA
11 foo     keyC    10
12 bar     keyC     6
13 baz     keyC     4
14  li     keyC    NA
15 qux     keyC    NA
```

Then you would only have to merge idx and melted_test once and keep only the columns you want.

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` solution could be to first `left_join` and then `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- data.frame(id = c("foo", "bar", "baz", "li", "qux"), keyA = c(NA, 1, 7, 8, 9), keyB = c(2, NA, NA, 3, NA), keyC = c(10, 6, 4, NA, NA))

idx <- data.frame(key = c(2, 10, 7, 4, 9), value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

idx <- left_join(idx, test[,c("keyA", "id")], by = c("key" = "keyA")) %>%
  left_join(test[,c("keyB", "id")], by = c("key" = "keyB")) %>%
  left_join(test[,c("keyC", "id")], by = c("key" = "keyC")) %>%
  mutate(value = coalesce(id.x,id.y,id)) %>%
  select(key, value)
```